# Anti-Derivative in defined up to a constant

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let f be holomorphic in D and let $\gamma$: $I$ $\rightarrow$ $D$ be a continuous path. Then anti-derivative of $f$ along $\gamma$ exists and is defined up to a constant.

The assumption here is to use the fact that a locally constant function defined on a connected set is constant on the whole set. And then use that to prove the above. But I do not know where to continue from there. Can someone offer some assistance?

Comment: What does "anti-derivative of $f$ along $\gamma$" mean?

Comment: @DanielFischer, a function $\gamma$: $I$ $\rightarrow$ $D$  is an anti-derivative of $f$ along the path $\gamma$ if the function is continuous on $I$ and for any point in the domain, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of the point so that $f$ has an anti-derivative.